# Using mysqli_query with mysql_query arguments

Tags: php, mysql, migration, php-7

I'm migrating from PHP 5 to PHP 7, and I made a grep to get all [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to change them to [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). The problem is, apparently the parametres changed using the procedural style.

```
mysql_query($query, $link_identifier)
mysqli_query($link_identifier, $query)
```

Even tho using the object oriented style they're still the same parametres.

Question is, will it work if I leave the parameters of `mysqli_query` as `$query, $link` thinking that the function is smart enough to detect which is which or I need to change them all to match the right parameters ?

Comment: No, that won't work. How should it. But: why not try and see what happens?

Comment: @NicoHaase do you have a source when you say no? In the particular case of `mysqli_query`. How should it? Because sometimes native functions are smart enough to detect which parameter you're passing, in this case it could detect which parameter is a string and which is an array automatically. I can't try it in my environment, long story.

Comment: Can you explain which function does so? I've heard of none in PHP

Comment: @NicoHaase I was more thinking about JS functions than PHP tbh (I've none on mind, though), thus my question if it was possible.

Comment: So, still: what would happen if you try it out? It should not be too hard to craft an example that makes you see that this is not possible in PHP

Answer (score -1):

Order of arguments isn't interchangeable.
[Php.net mysqli_query.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
[Php.net mysql_query.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

I also tested it.
mysql_query

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","login","pass");

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $link);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['col_name'];
}

mysql_close($link);
```

mysqli_query with with wrong order of arguments will produce: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given` code here:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "pass", "db");

//arguments in wrong order
if ($result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5", $link)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['col_name'];
    }
}
//produce
//Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Source? Your links are the same as mine.